# Visual Studio Code - Golang does not recognize import of html/template

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

Completely new to Visual Studio Code and Go ...

Trying to walk through a code sample, which requires the import of "html/template" -- however, Visual Studio Code shows the following (screen snapshot) when I try to add "html/template" to the import list:

[image]

No matter what I do, (i.e.: save the file) -- Visual Studio Code deletes the line containing "html/template" -- HOW do you add an import directive???

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using the `template` package in the file? Note that Go does not allow *unused* imports and the compiler will fail if it finds such imports in your files, so, therefore, a lot of editors will remove unused imports automatically. If you want to keep the import, then use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@mkopriva - Thanks -- Good Grief - yes - was following the tutorial -- which asked to insert "html/template" in the import list -- BUT -- I had not yet added any lines of code that referenced that package -- hence the "error" by the editor -- something simple that would trip up a complete newbie.

Comment: When using the Go extension, or most of modern editors, you won't need to manually import packages in most cases. As you start using it, the editors will autopopulate the imports.

Comment: And see this too. https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/discussions/1672

"[go]": {
 "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
  "source.organizeImports": false,
 },
}